# Copy file from application Internal memory to external storage in android?

Tags: android, memory, external, file-transfer, internal

I have an application that saves data to a file called 'sensorLog.txt'. I am not sure where exactly this is stored but I know this is only accessible by the applicationand it is in the internal memory.

I want to be able to write a copy the current file to an external storage when I click on a button "export". I have pasted a small bit of my program, But i am not sure how to copy sensorLog.txt file to the external storage.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private Button buttonStartService;
    private Button buttonStopService;
    private Button buttonSettings;
    private Button buttonExport;

    private TextView textStatus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_service);
        buttonStopService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop_service);
        buttonSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
        buttonExport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_export);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_status);


        buttonStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSensorService();
            }
        });

        buttonStopService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopSensorService();
            }
        });
        //export button listener

        buttonExport.setOnClickListener(export_handler);
    }

    public void startSensorService() {
        // Schedule
        AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SensorService.class);
        PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // 30 seconds
        long interval = 30 * 1000;

        scheduler.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, scheduledIntent);

        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Service started");

    }

    public void stopSensorService() {
        // Cancel
        AlarmManager scheduler = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SensorService.class);
        PendingIntent scheduledIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        scheduler.cancel(scheduledIntent);
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Service stopped");

    }

    View.OnClickListener export_handler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Here is the part I am not sure what to do. I want to copy a file    sensorLog.txt that has all my sensor information to sd card

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SD card detected");



            stopSensorService();

             File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),"SensorLog.txt");








             // delete file from the internal storage once exported
             context.deleteFile("SensorLog.txt");












            startSensorService();



        }
            else

            {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "No external storage detected(cannot copy file)");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Part where I create sensorLog.txt***(I dont think it is necessary to read for this question but just in case someone needs it)***:

```
private class SensorServiceLoggerTask extends AsyncTask<SensorFrame, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(SensorFrame... frames) {
            SensorFrame frame = frames[0];

            BufferedWriter bufWr = null;
            try {
                File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "SensorLog.txt");
                if (file.exists()) {
                    // Write to new file
                    bufWr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

                } else {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "New log file created");
                    // Append to existing file
                    bufWr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
                    // Write header
                    bufWr.append(sensorHeader.toString());
                }
                // Write frame
                bufWr.append(sensorFrame.toString());
                bufWr.flush();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Added frame to log");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // TODO: useful error handling
            } finally {
                // Cleanup
                if (bufWr != null) {
                    try {
                        bufWr.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // TODO: useful error handling
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I also have 2 more queries:

1. Lets say I want to append some information at the top of the file just before moving it how can I do that?
2. My aim is to transfer the sensorLog.txt file from internal to external storage when the export button is pressed. delete or empty the internal sensorLog.txt file and then the same thing happens again if i press export again, then I would have to rename my file when I export it right? would there not be a name clash? How do I handle that? could I give a name dynamically?

Thank you.

EDIT: Some corrections

```
View.OnClickListener export_handler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SD card detected");



            stopSensorService();

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "stopSensorService for file transfer");

                //make the timestamp the file name
                long TS = System.currentTimeMillis();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                stringBuilder.append(TS);
                stringBuilder.append(".txt");

                String file_name = stringBuilder.toString();

                //file name stored in file_name


                File file_ext = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),file_name);


// attempt to create this new directory


//read from sensorLog.txt file
                try
                {
                    file_ext.createNewFile();

                    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("sensorLog.txt");
                    if(file.exists())
                    {



                    FileInputStream read_file = openFileInput("sensorLog.txt");






                //read contents of internal file
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(read_file);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append("Timestamp of export to SD"+TS+"/n");
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                BufferedWriter bufWr = null;

               bufWr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file_ext, false));



                // Write header
                bufWr.append(sb.toString());
                inputStreamReader.close();
                bufWr.close();
                read_file.close();




                //delete sensor file once exported
                getApplicationContext().deleteFile("sensorLog.txt");
                    }

            }

                catch(Exception e){}
```

But for some reason my file is not getting stored in the SD card.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal). If you can read your sensorLog.txt file, then you can save it in a String and then save the string to a file in the external storage.

Comment: I did read it. The way I save a file is by appending an array with all the values.The way I would save an already existing file from internal to external memory is my doubt, Im not ael to figure out where the file is in the first place.

Comment: So can you read your file in your app? As I mentioned above, if you can read it you can write it to another file in external storage.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? My problem is I dont know how to get the location of sensor.txt on internal file and check its existance. I have edited my answer with a solution.